# Is it possible to ban all attachments from a Google Group?

Tags: google-groups

I help administrate a Google Group. We get a lot of these annoying, "See your attached invoice!" virus emails. And attached to the emails are *usually* zip files, sometimes pdfs, but just thinking about the infections I would get from those emails makes me itch.

I really can't think of a legitimate reason that anyone would have to send an email attachment to our group, so what I would *like* to do is tell Google, "If anyone sends an email with an attachment, just delete the email right out." It *would* be nice if perhaps someone from the admin group could send an email with attachments, but that's probably not necessary, so I'd be fine if it just blocks all emails with attachments.

I couldn't see any settings within Google Groups that would let me do that, though.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Group Manage page / Permissions / Posting permissions : Attach files ; 
only enable it for owners/managers.

[image: file attach permissions in Google Groups]